# Bind DataGrid to ObservableCollection<Tuple<bool, string>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to bind an `ObservableCollection<Tuple<bool, string>>` to a DataGrid in WPF.

XAML-code snippet:

```
<DataGrid Name="AvailableApps" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,30,5,5" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Application" Binding="{Binding Item2}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selection" Binding="{Binding Item1}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#-Code snippet:

```
AvailableApps.ItemsSource = Applications;
AvailableApps.IsReadOnly = false;
AvailableApps.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;
```

When I run the app with this code I get an exception saying that TwoWay- or OneWay-bindings do not work with read-only property of "Item1" of type "System.Tuple`2[System.Boolean,System.String]".

How can I make this work with `ObservableCollection<Tuple<bool, string>>`?

Comment: set `AvailableApps.ItemsSource = Applications;` after making column readonly: `AvailableApps.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;`. Really, Tuple is not woth it. make a custom class

Comment: Just set `Mode=OneWay` on both Bindings.

Answer (score 1):

A `Tuple<T1, T2>` is immutable so you won't be able to set its `Item1` property whether you use a `DataGrid` or not.

So if you want to be able change the values in your `DataGrid`, you should change the type of the source collection from `ObservableCollection<Tuple<bool, string>>` to `ObservableCollection<YourClass>` where `YourClass` is a class with a public settable `Item1` property (or whatever you choose to call it).